# How to make the shebang use the value of an environment variable

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, shebang

I have a file named `kong` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/openresty/bin/resty 

setmetatable(_G, nil)
pcall(require, "luarocks.loader")

package.path = "./?.lua;./?/init.lua;" .. package.path

require("kong.cmd.init")(arg)
```

I can execute it directly, like `kong start`.

But I want to use environment variables to modify the `resty` path freely. Such as I set an environment variable `export CURR_RESTY_PATH="XXXX"`, then modify the `kong` like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env ${CURR_RESTY_PATH}
```

I will get `/usr/bin/env: ${CURR_RESTY_PATH}: No such file or directory` if `kong start`

My question is how can I modify the `#!/usr/bin/env` to use environment variable?

Comment: Make the shebang point to a C executable you created yourself that checks that variable.

Comment: Or, easier, have a second intermediate script that's responsible for checking the variable and then running the real executable.

Comment: ...but shebang parsing is performed _by the OS kernel itself_. There are absolutely no fancy shell features available (for that matter, no non-fancy ones either).

Comment: Put it in your PATH or symlink it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is how can I modify the `#!/usr/bin/env` to use environment variable?

You can't. There are awful, ugly hacks -- but in the real world (where we need things to be reliable, even if interpreters are rewritten in the future to use two-pass parsers that `seek()` back and reread their source files from the beginning), use a separate script.

For example, you might rename your old `kong` to `kong.real`, and then create a `kong` script that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec "${CURR_RESTY_PATH:-/usr/local/openresty/bin/resty}" "${BASH_SOURCE}.real"
```

Comment: So should I delete the first line `#!/usr/bin/env /usr/local/openresty/bin/resty ` in `kong.real` ? I found it works whether I delete it or not

Comment: @YongqiZ: `env` with an absolute path as argument does not make any sense. What would you expect that it does. Try it on the commandline, before putting it into your script...

Comment: @YongqiZ, I would just use `#!/usr/local/openresty/bin/resty` -- that way you're specifying a default to use if the `.real` script is called directly. Leaving the shebang off entirely is bad form -- it makes your program's behavior depend on what's trying to start it. (Shell interpreters mostly fall back to trying to treat the thing as a shell script, other executables typically just give up as soon as an `execve()` call fails).